# Sort results by distance and get the distance between them and the query point

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I currently sort results by distance for my model using:

**views.py**

```
    SearchPoint = Point(long, lat)    
    res = Model.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(SearchPoint, D(m=2000)))
               .annotate(distance=Distance('location', SearchPoint))
               .order_by('distance')
```

This allows me to sort the results which are within 2000m by `distance`.

Now I would like to display also the distance between the searcher which is given by `SearchPoint` and the results of my `Model`.

**Models.py**
In my model class I define the following property:

```
@property
def distance_to_searcher(self):
    distance =self.location.distance(SearchPoint)
    return distance * 100
```

but I get the following error:

> name 'SearchPoint' is not defined

I understand that this is not defined because it gets defined in the `views.py` file, which is a GET request and takes long and lat parameters from the URL and puts them into `Point()` class.

Ideally, I would round up the distance to a nice number.

EDIT: I define the `SearchPoint` in **views.py**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        form = LocationForm(self.request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            SearchPoint=Point(form.cleaned_data['Lng'],form.cleaned_data['Lat'])
        else:
            form = LocationForm()
            SearchPoint=Point(0,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating this query:

```
res = Model.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(SearchPoint, D(m=2000)))
                   .annotate(distance=Distance('location', SearchPoint))
                   .order_by('distance')
```

with the use of `annotate`, you are "adding" a field named `distance` to every model object that query returns.

That said, if you do:

```
for item in res:
    print(item.distance)
```

you will get the distance of every model object to the `SearchPoint`.

---

If you absolutely want to use a `@property` in your model, you should define it in such a way that accepts the `SearchPoint` as an argument:

```
@property
def distance_to_searcher(self, search_point):
    distance=self.location.distance(search_point)
    return distance * 100
```

But you will have to modify your query as well:

```
res = Model.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(SearchPoint, D(m=2000)))
                   .order_by('distance')
```

since you no longer need to use annotate to create a `distance` field in your queryset.
Now if you do:

```
for item in res:
    print(item.distance_to_searcher(SearchPoint))
```

you will have the same result as above.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing. It seems that in the template, it automatically calculates the distance in m and in float. How would I round up to 1 decimal place with km? I tried playing with res.distance|floatformat:0 , but it seems to be a string rather than number.

Comment: @Roma you can manipulate the `distance` field to return the `Distance` in km and you can change what the response of your view return in order to format the float there and not in the template! (Search and try those and if you still have a problem you can make another post with you question here on SO)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to be simply calling `.distance` in my template. The `res` variable already has distance as attribute, no need for additional property.